# Not able to open grpc-java repo on intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, grpc

I have cloned the grpc-java project in this [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java).

I am trying to open the same in intellij.

I am opening the grpc-java directory.

I am getting this error message.

```
"Unable to find method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V'."
```

The exception stack trace on intellij logs are:

```
2016-05-17 17:35:39,463 [26654390]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:213)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:688)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:672)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

29
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':grpc-all'.
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:101)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':grpc-all'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:157)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:162)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientConfigurer.configureSslSocketConnectionFactory(HttpClientConfigurer.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.getClient(HttpClientHelper.java:123)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getRawResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:72)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.HttpPluginResolutionServiceClient.request(HttpPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:86)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.HttpPluginResolutionServiceClient.queryPluginMetadata(HttpPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient$1.create(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient$1.create(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:58)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.fetch(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:110)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.maybeFetch(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:103)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.maybeFetch(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:91)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.queryPluginMetadata(PersistentCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:67)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient$1.create(InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:47)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient$1.create(InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:45)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.getResponse(InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:76)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.queryPluginMetadata(InMemoryCachingPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:42)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.DeprecationListeningPluginResolutionServiceClient.queryPluginMetadata(DeprecationListeningPluginResolutionServiceClient.java:48)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.service.internal.PluginResolutionServiceResolver.resolve(PluginResolutionServiceResolver.java:84)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.CompositePluginResolver.resolve(CompositePluginResolver.java:33)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.NotNonCorePluginOnClasspathCheckPluginResolver.resolve(NotNonCorePluginOnClasspathCheckPluginResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:188)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.access$000(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:44)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1.transform(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$1.transform(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:65)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:188)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:183)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:65)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:140)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:597)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:589)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:236)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:130)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
        at 
org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 60 more
    2016-05-17 17:35:39,464 [26654391]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Unable to find method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V'. 
    com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to find method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V'.
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:274)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:182)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:347)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:692)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:672)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:228)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:111)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:72)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Please please help me with this. I have spent 3 hours and nowhere on this.

Updated.

Comment: try to open gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties and change https:// to http:// and then try to reimport the project

Comment: @Dodge I did change that. It did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to work around this issue. I just switched the OS I was using and was able to open the same with Intellij as well as run the gradle for the java example. I am not quite sure what the issue really was in the other OS. As it started all of a sudden, I might have made some accidental high level configuration changes that I am still unaware of. :D.

Thank you all.